# Run system command in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, system-calls

I have the below server function which takes two input files from the inputFile tab in the ui.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("CF", label = "CF"),
  fileInput("ED", label = "ED"),
  actionButton("Run", "Run")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    cf_file <- reactive({ 
        cfFile <- input$CF
        return(cfFile$datapath)
    })

    ed_file <- reactive({ 
        edFile <- input$ED
        return(edFile$datapath)
    })

    table_content <- eventReactive(input$Run, {
        req(input$ED$datapath)
        req(input$CF$datapath)
        file_ed <- ed_file()
        file_cf <- cf_file()

        ##the system command uses external program which takes input files (file_cf and file_ed) from fileInput. The command will look like:
        #/bin/qt con ed -i file_cf -p file_ed > file_ed.db#

        system(paste("/bin/qt con ed -i", file_cf, "-p", file_ed, ">", file_ed,".db" ))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have two issues here:

1) The system command is not working here which gives the error:

```
qt: Error reading file '/var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpISFd3V/aac5eff9961beb644d8ec5e0/0.phe': End of file
```

The system command is taking the two input files and writing to an output file by adding ".db" to one of the inputFile. Could anyone point what is wrong in the above system command?

I have followed the similar query at `https://community.rstudio.com/t/system-call-within-r-shiny/11405/3`

2) If the system command works, how can i render the output in the output file to table_content?

**Tries & Errors:**
I tried with `paste0()` but no luck, this time with a different error where it is not reading the input files file_cf and file_ed.

```
 system(paste0("/bin/qt con ed -i ", file_cf, " -p ", file_ed, " > ", file_ed,".db"))

`Error accessing  file '/var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpjqfSir/6a3263bc18297e4b6567979e/0.cf -p/var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpjqfSir/02b964d65d0f0b1a9476a8be/0.ed': No such file or directory`
```

Then using system2:

```
system2(paste0("/bin/qt con ed -i ",file_cf, " -p ", file_ed, " > ", file_ed,".db" ))

sh: /bin/qt con ed -i /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpjqfSir/ebc57ae122e171f074281112/0.cf -p /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpjqfSir/15a75f8fbe5992bd82ab8a22/0.ed > /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmpjqfSir/15a75f8fbe5992bd82ab8a22/0.ed.db: No such file or directory
Warning in system2(paste0("/bin/qt con ed -i ",  :
  error in running command
```

The above sh: command generated by R when run in shell outside R, using the tmp paths it works and can see the output files in the tmp path. But when it is run in R using the `system` and `paste0` it gives the above error.

Comment: have you tried to create the file in the www Folder or tried using https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/addResourcePath.html?

Comment: I tried the way i have shown above. It fails reading the input file and writing the output. Could you give an example using www folder or addResourcePath?

Comment: The Input files are stored in an Temp folder, thats why youre getting the weird path names. But looking at the 2nd error, it takes the whole command as file. And i also see wrong whitespaces before the -p and >.. Or is that just from the output?

Comment: it is only in the output, There is no space in the command itself

Comment: i have updated the `system2(paste0())` with spaces as shown above and it has the same error. It somehow reads the file extension of the input files correctly but not the file name.

Comment: `Warning: Error in shell: could not find function "shell"`

Comment: Could you print out the command created in Shiny and try to call it via a normal shell?

Comment: `/bin/qt con ed -i file.gz -p Test.ed  > Test.ed.db`  the command works in the mac terminal and gives the output. Still could not figure out why it fails with the Shiny command

Comment: No, i mean the command that is created in the eventReactive, with the paths to the temp files.

Comment: It works well in a normal shell and i can see the output file using the temp paths. I do not understand what's happening within R.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which files you are using as inputs, so I just used images and looked at the outcoming system command which would be like that:

```
/bin/qt con ed -i C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohWHcF/08b770ef9620ce852841b792/0.png -p C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohWHcF/b2fdf736bf904194d709b66c/0.png > C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohWHcF/b2fdf736bf904194d709b66c/0.png .db
```

The problem is at the end of the line, because there is a whitespace before `.db`.
I dont know if that will solve your problem, but it may be a first step ;)

So just try this command:

```
paste0("/bin/qt con ed -i ", file_cf, " -p ", file_ed, " > ", file_ed,".db")
```

It uses `paste0`, which doesn't include whitespaces, so you include them in the string parts. The last input of the system command will have double extensions though (like `.png.db`). To get rid of that you could use:

```
file_ed2 <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(file_ed)
```

and assign this to the last system cmd input.

If that still does'nt wok, you could also try out the `system2` command insteand of `system`. That worked sometimes better for me.

To answer **question 2**, I need to know what kind of output it is and how to load and render it? But in any case, maybe the `reactivePoll` function could be working here.

-- App

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("CF", label = "CF"),
  fileInput("ED", label = "ED"),
  actionButton("Run", "Run"),
  verbatimTextOutput("code")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cf_file <- reactive({ 
    cfFile <- input$CF
    return(cfFile$datapath)
  })

  ed_file <- reactive({ 
    edFile <- input$ED
    return(edFile$datapath)
  })

  table_content <- eventReactive(input$Run, {
    req(input$ED$datapath)
    req(input$CF$datapath)
    file_ed <- ed_file()
    file_cf <- cf_file()

    file_ed2 <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(file_ed)

    paste0("/bin/qt con ed -i ", file_cf, " -p ", file_ed, " > ", file_ed2,".db")
  })

  output$code <- renderText({
    req(table_content())
    table_content()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I tried but no luck, this time with a different error where it is not reading the input files

Comment: OP updated with errors. And `file_ed2` is not required in my case as i need double extension.